# Selenium Webdriver Tests are failed in jenkins due to No Such element exception or stale element exception

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, maven-surefire-plugin

I have integrated Test automation Framework with Jenkins and when we run the same suite using mvn clean install the suite runs smoothly. but when we run the same suite using Jenkins jobs, mostly of test's get failed showing Webdriver exceptions like NoSuchElementException or staleelementexception.

How do i handle this issue with jenkins jobs execution?

Comment: If test works fine in local, it should work in Jenkins as well. Run the Jenkins job quite often and try to identify the pattern in which its failing. Probably, you may get some idea. Take screenshots for each actions and verify it. We make scripts in mac and run it in Windows Slave machine. Its working fine.

Comment: I keep on getting the same error in Jenkins.